itkwidgets not working with JupyterNotebook
I am trying to run a workflow through Jupyternotebook and am having issue with itkwidgets. The error I receive is "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'itkwidgets'". The problem is, I have installed itkwidgets.

I think the issue has to do with my install of itkwidgets. When I try to install itkwidgets using pip install itkwidgets I get the output below. I'm questioning why it is saved in so many different locations, especially considering I cleared my computer completely in the process of trying to figure this out.
(base) amarabrinks@Amara-Brinks-Computer:~$ pip install itkwidget 

Requirement already satisfied: itkwidgets in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.14.0)

Requirement already satisfied: itk-core>=4.13.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (5.4.0)

Requirement already satisfied: ipydatawidgets>=3.2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (4.3.2)

Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=7.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (7.8.1)

Requirement already satisfied: ipympl in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (0.9.4)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (1.26.4)

Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (1.13.1)

Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (1.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: zstandard in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from itkwidgets) (0.22.0)

Requirement already satisfied: traittypes>=0.2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipydatawidgets>=3.2.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.1)

Requirement already satisfied: comm>=0.1.3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.1)

Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils~=0.2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (5.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (3.6.6)

Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (8.21.0)

Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets<3,>=1.0.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.0.0)

Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipympl->itkwidgets) (3.8.4)

Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipympl->itkwidgets) (10.3.0)

Requirement already satisfied: decorator in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (5.1.1)

Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.18.1)

Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.1.6)

Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.41 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (3.0.43)

Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.15.1)

Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (4.8.0)

Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (1.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (0.11.0)

Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (4.51.0)

Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (1.4.4)

Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (23.2)

Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (3.0.9)

Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.4.0->ipympl->itkwidgets) (2.9.0.post0)

Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.4.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (6.4.13)

Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.8.3)

Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (3.1.4)

Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (6.4.1)

Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (25.1.2)

Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (21.3.0)

Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (5.7.2)

Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.4 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (8.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (5.9.2)

Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert>=5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (7.10.0)

Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio>=1.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (6.28.0)

Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.8.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.8.2)

Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.17.1)

Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.14.1)

Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.7.0)

Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.41->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.5)

Requirement already satisfied: executing in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.8.3)

Requirement already satisfied: asttokens in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.0.5)

Requirement already satisfied: pure-eval in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.2.2)

Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (3.10.0)

Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (4.12.3)

Requirement already satisfied: bleach!=5.0.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (4.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.7.1)

Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.1.2)

Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe>=2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.1.3)

Requirement already satisfied: mistune<4,>=2.0.3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.0.4)

Requirement already satisfied: nbclient>=0.5.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.8.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.5.0)

Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.2.1)

Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.16.2)

Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (4.19.2)

Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi-bindings in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (21.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: debugpy>=1.6.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.6.7)

Requirement already satisfied: psutil in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (5.9.0)

Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from bleach!=5.0.0->nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.5.1)

Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=22.2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (23.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema-specifications>=2023.03.6 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2023.7.1)

Requirement already satisfied: referencing>=0.28.4 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.30.2)

Requirement already satisfied: rpds-py>=0.7.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (0.10.6)

Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (1.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.5)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.6->ipywidgets>=7.4.0->itkwidgets) (2.21)


When I look into the extensions installed for jupyter using "Jupyter labextension list" I see the following:
`sys_prefix` level settings are read-only, using `user` level for migration to `lockedExtensions`
JupyterLab v4.2.5
/home/amarabrinks/.local/share/jupyter/labextensions
        jupyterlab_pygments v0.3.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
        @jupyter-notebook/lab-extension v7.2.2 enabled OK
        @voila-dashboards/jupyterlab-preview v2.3.7 enabled OK (python, voila)
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.13 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
   app dir: /home/amarabrinks/.local/share/jupyter/lab



At this point I have tried everything my fairly novice skill level can think of. I've deleted and reinstalled anaconda, jupyter, pip, nodejs, itkwidgets, ipywidgets.



First, you should endeavor to use Anaconda/conda as much as possible because by installing it you choose it as your primary package manager. Henceforth, only ever use pip if there is no conda recipe. itkwidgets has a recipe indicated here, with the command you should be using, & so you should not be using pip for itkwidgets here. Second, I cannot tell what environment you Jupyter is using or if you know you have to make a kernel and connect that kernel to the conda environment?

 The two top-scoring answers here give you options for how to connect those things. You want to make a conda environment, activate it, install itkwidgets. Then install a kernel and then launch Jupyter using and choose to use that kernel. Anaconda Cloud or MyBinder are nice places to practice with this separate from your system if you are concerned about it. In fact, they used to  here offer a binder badge you could just click on to use it, but that is outdated now.
